# How do I update RubyInstaller w/out updating Ruby ver itself?

Tags: ruby, msys, rubyinstaller

I was advised to update to latest RubyInstaller version in order to install specific gem:

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1329

Not ready to migrate to new Ruby version itself as it could compromise some existing dependencies.
Current Ruby version I am on is 3.0.2

How do I update RubyInstaller w/out updating Ruby ver itself?
Thx

Read a lot page https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/wiki/For-gem-developers but getting even more confused :)